# OpenAM Apache Agent + Apache 64bit Error

Tags: windows, apache, 64-bit, openam

I'm using OpenAM 11.0 and Apache Agent 3.3.0.

With my PC (Development Environment), it's OK.

- Windows 7 Enterprise K 64bit
- Apache 2.4 32 bit
- Apache Agent 3.3.0 windows 32bit

  But, Production Environment, it's not OK.
- Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise SP1

  I tried to use Apache 32bit, but failed. (I don't understand exactly. There are 'Program Files (x86)' and 'Windows\SysWOW64', but when I run httpd.exe, Windows shows 0000007b Error and terminated.)

  So, I used Apache 64bit.

  After install Apache Agent to Apache 64bit, I tried to run Apache, but it showed something like following message.

-=-=-
C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Apache24-VC11\bin>httpd
httpd: Syntax error on line 532 of C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/Apache24-VC11/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/apache24_agent/Agent_001/config/dsame.conf: Cannot load C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/apache24_agent/bin/libamapc24.dll into server: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
-=-=-

I found solution about this situation at azlabs page(http://azlabs.blogspot.kr/2014/01/openam-policy-agent-330-for-apache.html), but it couldn't help my case.

As I see, he didn't know exact why about this situation.

Hmm...

Forgerock doesn't distribute win64 version of Apache Agent seperately.

Where can I find solution?

Please...

Comment: Thank you for your comments.
Until now I just tested for constitution. Now We changed constitution. OpenAM Server 11 (from build) + Apache 2.2 + Apache Agent 3.0.4 (from archived with CDDL)

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong but there is no support for 64bits. You need to install the agent on 32bit Apache httpd.

Comment: Thank you...
 I found the reason of 32bit Apache Error. It came from inadequate VC(Vidual Studio Runtime) version. After I set up the proper VC, Apache 32bit ran successfully, so I could apply 32bit Apache Agent.